# Can't figure out how to create texture from a font-surface

Tags: c, sdl2, ttf

I can't seem to be able to render my font, it crashes and I can't figure out why. It seems to load the font correctly, but the parts relating to surface crashes.

Why does my texture crash?

---

Here is the code bits relating to it. SDL2 and TTF has been initialized properly.

```
        TTF_Font *arial;
        SDL_Color mm_txt_color = {255, 255, 255, 0};
        SDL_Texture *myTexture;
        SDL_Rect myRect;
        load_font(MM_FONT_ARIAL, 18,  &arial);

        get_text_and_rect(0, 0, "Exit", arial, &myTexture, &myRect);


int load_font(char *filepath, int size, TTF_Font **font)
{
    (*font) == TTF_OpenFont(filepath, size);
    if((*font) == NULL ) {
        printf("ERROR: Failed to load font: %s.\n", filepath);
        return FAILURE;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}


    void get_text_and_rect(int x, int y, char *text, TTF_Font *font, 
        SDL_Texture **texture, SDL_Rect *rect)
    {
        int text_width;
        int text_height;
        SDL_Surface *surface;
        SDL_Color textColor = {255, 255, 255, 0};

        surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text, textColor);
        *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
        text_width = surface->w;
        text_height = surface->h;
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        rect->x = x;
        rect->y = y;
        rect->w = text_width;
        rect->h = text_height;
    }
```

Comment: Did you check what `TTF_RenderText` returns? Do you check `SDL_GetError()`?

Comment: well i know that it crashes on surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(...), I just don't know why.

Comment: Solved it using TTF_GetError(), nothing really wrong with the code, just failed to enter correct filepath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using printf("%s\n", TTF_GetError()); i got the answer that the font hadn't been loaded correctly, so you provided the correct answer, nothing with the code but just the entered filepath on my part.